# How to safely provide kubeconfig to kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubeconfig

Our users are allowed to access Kubernetes clusters only from the management station, there is no possibility to access the API directly from their laptops/workstations.

Every user posses kubeconfig with relevant secrets belonging to this particular user. As the kubeconfig also contains the token used to authenticate against the Kubernetes API, it is not possible to store the kubeconfig "as is" on the management station file system.

Is there any way how to provide the token/kubeconfig to kubectl e.g. via STDIN, not exposing it to other users (e.g. admin of the management station) on the file system?

Answer (score 7):

You could use bash process substitution to pass the entire `kubeconfig` to `kubectl` without saving it to a filesystem.

Something like this works for CI systems:

1. Base64-encode your `kubeconfig` and store it securely

```
export KUBECONFIG_DATA=$(cat kubeconfig | base64 -w0)
```

2. Use process substitution to Base64-decode and pass it directly to `kubectl`:

```
kubectl --kubeconfig <(echo $KUBECONFIG_DATA | base64 --decode) ...
```

Comment: for disposable shell one can do the following trick
 `alias kubectl='kubectl --kubeconfig <(echo $KUBECONFIG_DATA | base64 --decode)'` 
and then use `kubectl` as usual

Answer (score 2):

So far I have used the following solution:

- User specifies an empty token in the kubeconfig file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
 - name: foo.bar
  user:
    token:
```

- User sets the TOKEN variable without echoing it

```
read -s TOKEN
```

- User specifies the token as paramater to kubectl

```
kubectl --kubeconfig /home/foo.bar/kubeconfig --token $TOKEN get nodes
```

Answer (score 0):

Activate account and download credentials using a service account.

```
 gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=${PULL_KEYFILE} --project PROJECT_NAME
 gcloud container clusters get-credentials CLUSTER_NAME --zone ZONE
 //use kubectl as you would do
 kubectl create namespace ${NAMESPACE} --dry-run -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

Comment: We are running our own Kubernetes clusters so no "gcloud" is available. Anyway, I do not see how this addresses the storage of kubeconfig on the disk.

Comment: gcloud container credentials writes to kubeconfig file and gets configured